# RabbitMQ / Celery with Django hangs on delay/ready/etc - No useful log info

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

So I just setup celery and rabbitmq, created my user, setup the vhost, mapped the user to the vhost, and ran the celery daemon succesfully (or so I assume)

```
(queuetest)corky@corky-server:~/projects/queuetest$ ./manage.py celeryd
 celery@corky-server v0.9.5 is starting.
 Configuration ->
. broker -> amqp://celery@localhost:5672/
. queues ->
. celery -> exchange:celery (direct) binding:celery
. concurrency -> 2
. loader -> celery.loaders.djangoapp
. logfile -> [stderr]@WARNING
. events -> OFF
. beat -> OFF

Celery has started.
```

I created a user of "celery" because I wasn't feeling very inventive in this case.

When I try to do one of the simple examples within the celery docs:

```
>>> from tasks import add
>>> r = add.delay(2, 2)
>>> r
<AsyncResult: 16235ea3-c7d6-4cce-9387-5c6285312c7c>
>>> r.ready()
(hangs for eternity.)
```

So I checked the FAQ wondering what else could be up and it told me this is a common bug due to user permissions, so I triple checked those, nothing, made another new user, still nothing. If I import `DjangoBrokerConnection` from `carrot.connection` and get the information, it matches up with what's in my celery settings. The FAQ stated to check your log file.

My `rabbit.log` file isn't very helpful in this situation, simply showing:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 26-Jan-2010::11:58:22 ===
accepted TCP connection on 0.0.0.0:5672 from 127.0.0.1:60572

=INFO REPORT==== 26-Jan-2010::11:58:22 ===
starting TCP connection <0.1120.0> from 127.0.0.1:60572
```

And so forth. At this point, I'm at a loss as to what else my problem could be. I'm running Ubuntu Jaunty and installed RabbitMQ from apt-get.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to run celeryd with --loglevel=INFO, so you can see if the task is being received and processed or not. Also, what result backend are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just fixed a really ugly bug that would only show up for new users that would have caused this. (http://github.com/ask/celery/commit/a9c1316b15055b67ee3c38d294461fa82ed6d2b5)

Please pull from the master branch at github. If it still doesn't work you 
probably have to stop rabbitmq, remove the rabbitmq database directory (usually `/var/lib/rabbitmq`) and start rabbitmq again)

Really sorry for the inconvenience.
The bug happened because we recently changed the name of the consumers routing key option to "binding key", but the amqp libraries still use `routing_key` and we forgot to rewrite the option.

Comment: Thank you .. sorry for the late reply, wow I've been busy! But this worked. Also, grats on the 1.0 release :)

Comment: Got me on this one as well :>

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this: it really does seem to help to remove your /var/lib/rabbitmq, even if the problem seems to go away with updating celery. I was seeing lots of unreliability and unpredictability until I did so.