# celery .delay hangs (recent, not an auth problem)

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I am running Celery 2.2.4/djCelery 2.2.4, using RabbitMQ 2.1.1 as a backend. I recently brought online two new celery servers -- I had been running 2 workers across two machines with a total of ~18 threads and on my new souped up boxes (36g RAM + dual hyper-threaded quad-core), I am running 10 workers with 8 threads each, for a total of 180 threads -- my tasks are all pretty small so this should be fine.

The nodes have been running fine for the last few days, but today I noticed that `.delaay()` is hanging. When I interrupt it, I see a traceback that points here:

```
File "/home/django/deployed/releases/20110608183345/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/celery/task/base.py", line 324, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/home/django/deployed/releases/20110608183345/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/celery/task/base.py", line 449, in apply_async
    publish.close()
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/kombu/compat.py", line 108, in close
    self.backend.close()
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py", line 194, in close
    (20, 41),    # Channel.close_ok
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.py", line 89, in wait
    self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 198, in _wait_method
    self.method_reader.read_method()
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/method_framing.py", line 212, in read_method
    self._next_method()
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/method_framing.py", line 127, in _next_method
    frame_type, channel, payload = self.source.read_frame()
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 109, in read_frame
    frame_type, channel, size = unpack('>BHI', self._read(7))
File "/home/django/deployed/virtual-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py", line 200, in _read
    s = self.sock.recv(65536)
```

I've checked the Rabbit logs, and I see it the process trying to connect as:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 12-Jun-2011::22:58:12 ===
accepted TCP connection on 0.0.0.0:5672 from x.x.x.x:48569
```

I have my Celery log level set to `INFO`, but I don't see anything particularly interesting in the Celery logs EXCEPT that 2 of the workers can't connect to the broker:

```
[2011-06-12 22:41:08,033: ERROR/MainProcess] Consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish connection...
```

All of the other nodes are able to connect without issue.

I know that there was a posting ( [RabbitMQ / Celery with Django hangs on delay/ready/etc - No useful log info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141083/rabbitmq-celery-with-django-hangs-on-delay-ready-etc-no-useful-log-info) ) last year of a similar nature, but I'm pretty certain that this is different. Could it be that the sheer number of workers is creating some sort of a race condition in `amqplib` -- I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/issues/detail?id=26) thread which seems to indicate that `amqplib` is not thread-safe, not sure if this matters for Celery.

**EDIT:** I've tried `celeryctl purge` on both nodes -- on one it succeeds, but on the other it fails with the following AMQP error:

```
AMQPConnectionException(reply_code, reply_text, (class_id, method_id))
    amqplib.client_0_8.exceptions.AMQPConnectionException: 
    (530, u"NOT_ALLOWED - cannot redeclare exchange 'XXXXX' in vhost 'XXXXX' 
     with different type, durable or autodelete   value", (40, 10), 'Channel.exchange_declare')
```

On both nodes, `inspect stats` hangs with the "can't close connection" traceback above. I'm at a loss here.

**EDIT2:** I was able to delete the offending exchange using `exchange.delete` from `camqadm` and now the second node hangs too :(.

**EDIT3:** One thing that also recently changed is that I added an additional vhost to rabbitmq, which my staging node connects to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully this will save somebody a lot of time...though it certainly does not save me any embarrassment:

`/var` was full on the server that was running rabbit. With all of the nodes that I added, rabbit was doing a lot more logging and it filled up `/var` -- I couldn't write to `/var/lib/rabbitmq`, and so no messages were going through.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, but not the same cause, for anyone else who stumbles up on this, mine was solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591450/284164 -- I wasn't importing the celery app at the project level, and `.delay()` was hanging until I added that.