# Celery hangs on ready()

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Almost an exact duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141083/rabbitmq-celery-with-django-hangs-on-delay-ready-etc-no-useful-log-info), but the answer does not help me. I have installed Erlang, Celery and RabbitMQ and set up Celery to use AMQP as the backend and broker. I've followed the [quickstart example](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) (create a task which adds two numbers together) exactly, but when I get to issuing the `result.ready()` command, the Celery process just hangs.

- It's not an auth problem (quadruple checked and tested invalid logins)
- It's not an out of disk space error as per the previous SO question (>800mb free)
- The worker is up and running ("consumer: Ready to accept tasks!")
- The MQ is up and running ("broker running")
- I can see Celery connecting to RabbitMQ ("accepting AMQP connection  (ip -> ip)")
- I think it's a matter of my Python script not connecting to the Celery worker process correctly. Could it be because I'm trying to run this on a Raspberry Pi? The OS is very low on available memory.

Am tearing my hair out here. Any help welcomed!

Comment: Does the consumer start executing the task at all? Is it hanging when you try to get the result after the task it's done, or the consumer doesn't receive the task at all?

Comment: No the consumer (worker) does not receive the task at all, which would indicate a communicate failure in the broker, I think. Using the same code with Redis instead of RabbitMQ works immediately, so it's not a code issue.

Comment: Did you try to list the queue contents with: rabbitmqadmin list  queues -> to see if the messages are in your queues? If they don't reach your consumer and the publisher published them, they should still be visible in the queues when you list the queues.

Comment: I've set up rabbitmqadmin and issued the `list queues` command, and got an error: `*** Could not connect: [ErrNo 97] Address family not supported by protocol`, which is odd. Looks like an IPv6 compatibility issue on the pi, perhaps. I'll do some more digging and report back.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of trial and error I found that adding the following into my `celeryconfig.py` resulted in the call to `ready()` returning `True`. Maybe not an ideal solution, but at least one which gets the process un-stuck and returning a proper value.

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

Before implementing this workaround (not a true solution, in my eyes) you should probably read the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html?highlight=celery_always_eager#std%3asetting-CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER) to make sure that you understand what this does;

> ... tasks will be executed locally instead of being sent to the queue.

Which kind of negates the reason for using Celery in the first place, so in the end I gave up and used Redis instead of AMQP. Works like a charm.

Comment: If I understand correct, 'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True' means you are calling the functionality without a helper process.